# Vue.js mixins call parent method in overridden implementation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

I'm using [vuejs-datepicker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker) component in a project however I need some custom behaviour that's why I decided to create my own datepicker and inject vuejs-datepicker as a mixin. The solution works fine but I'm looking for a way to call the parent method inside my overridden one. That's how my component looks for now:

```
  import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'

  export default {
    props: {
      /**
       * My custom property startDate to open a calendar on the given date by default
       */
      startDate: {
        validator: function (val) {
          return val === null || val instanceof Date || typeof val === 'string'
        },
        default: new Date()
      }
    },

    mixins: [ Datepicker ],

    methods: {
      /**
       * I override parent method setPageDate to read default startDate when none is specified
       */
      setPageDate (date) {
        // my code to set default date from the property
        if (!date) {
          date = this.startDate
        }

        // this part is the same as in the original method
        this.pageDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1, date.getHours(), date.getMinutes()).getTime()
      }
    }
  }
```

Just one line of copied code isn't a big deal but I expect I need to override more methods in the future. So I'm looking for the best way to call that parent method inside my implementation, something like `this.parent(date)` or `this.super(date)`. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Looks like there's a library for this: https://dev.to/ashraful/call-super-method-in-vue-component-3pl2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no `super` or anything like that. You *could* do something like this:

```
  setPageDate (date) {
    // my code to set default date from the property
    if (!date) {
      date = this.startDate
    }

    Datepicker.methods.setPageDate.call(this, date)
  }
```

Comment: indeed, plain JS solution works fine there but I thought maybe Vue.js provides something else. Thank you!